# How to mock a class that depends on class from vendor (AwsClient)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Hi I am trying to write unit tests for a specific case where I have to test a class that is depending on `Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient` that comes from `aws-sdk-php` package.

Here is how my class look like:

```php
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\Result;

class DynamoDbService implements DynamoDbServiceInterface
{
    protected DynamoDbClient $client; // Class from aws-sdk-php 

    public function __construct(DynamoDbClient $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function describe(string $tableName): Result
    {
        $result = $this->client->describeTable([
            'TableName' => $tableName
        ]);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I came up with a solution but it does not actually work:

```php
class DynamoDbServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testDescribe()
    {
        $client = $this->createMock(DynamoDbClient::class);
        $resultMock = $this->createMock(Result::class);

        $client
            ->method('describeTable')
            ->will($this->returnValue($resultMock));

        $dynamoDbService = new DynamoDbService($client);

        $result = $dynamoDbService->describe('table_example_name');
        $this->assertInstanceOf($result, Result::class);
    }
}
```

My solution gave me an error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\DynamoDbServiceTest::testDescribe
PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MethodCannotBeConfiguredException: Trying to configure method "describeTable" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

/home/project/src/tests/unit/DynamoDbServiceTest.php:21
```

In the end the problem is mocking an `AwsClient` class. It does not have a `describeTable` method, but it is rather called by using magic method `__call`. How can I get a working solution and mock such a class?

Answer (score 2):

I'd move the DynamoDbService in a separate interface, and inject the interface instead of the aws object.

I had a similar approach with Stripe SDK,

The main advantage is to avoid fixing your code if amazon updates its SDK and have better controls about which features of the SDK you're using

```
interface StripeGatewayInterface
{
    public function createCustomer(Customer $customer): string;
}


class Stripe implements StripeGatewayInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly StripeClient $stripe
    ) {
    }

    // your methods with the SDK
}
```

Comment: I believe I have the same solution. I have my own classes: `DynamoDbService` and `DynamoDbServiceInterface`. What I don't have is a dependency setup using interface. I use `DynamoDbClient` instead of `AwsClient`. But I believe this will not be a solution for my case.

Comment: You can also use this interface to "rename" those methods and change their signature

Comment: In my example, I call $sthis->stripeClient->customers->create(), using an interface is cleaner here IMO because it avoid adding complexity somewhere else in the code

Comment: I mean, your interface does not have to follow the SDK  methods and  signatures

Answer (score 0):

Okey I believe I found an anwser. If you came here with the same problem you need to trigger mock builder first with using `addMethods` and later on use this mock for setting behaviour of mock methods.

```php
class DynamoDbServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testDescribe()
    {
        $resultMock = $this->createMock(Result::class);

        $client = $this->getMockBuilder(DynamoDbClient::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->addMethods(['describeTable'])
            ->getMock();

        $client->method('describeTable')->will($this->returnValue($resultMock));

        $dynamoDbService = new DynamoDbService($client);

        $result = $dynamoDbService->describe('table_example_name');
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Result::class, $result);
    }
}
```